# Mismatch in point locations between QGIS and my GPSMAP65S

Tags: qgis, gps

I identified at distance (maps) different points on the island I am working on, Martinique (in the French West Indies). I noted their coordinates in the same system as my QGIS map (WGS 84) as well as my GPS (GPSMAP65S). While the points are perfectly located in my QGIS map, there is a shift (apparently north-eastwards) on my GPS so well that some of my points end up in the water when read on the GPS. I checked if there was a problem with my waypoints directly in my GPX file (the file I used to implement my points in my GPS from QGIS), but again the points of my GPX data have the same and good coordinates. On my GPS then, same thing ; when I click on my points, the latter have the same coordinates but as I said they do not land on the same position as on my QGIS map. I recalibrated my GPS in case the problem was coming from this, but nothing changed. We also tried on another GPS (GPSMAP64sx) that was used here in Martinique for a long time by a colleague (mine was freshly brought), and again we observed the same shift. Finally, I created a waypoint directly on my GPS and checked if it was well located on my QGIS map, and yes it is perfectly. Would you have any idea about what could be the solution?

Here is a sample of my points, latitude on the left and longitude on the right (WGS 84) :

14.826977    -61.209742

14.647774    -61.130210

14.616790    -61.103494

14.771036    -61.008454

14.755228    -60.908581

14.770594    -60.893056

14.761048    -60.934866

14.684920    -61.006865

14.684003    -60.949738

14.508984    -60.828018

14.559455    -60.938621

Comment: Just an idea: the file you are importing is using a different datum than your GPS, and your GPS is ignoring/not finding this information. When exporting from the GPS to a file, the proper datum/CRS is set and is recognized by QGIS

Comment: Thank you for your comment: I checked that but my GPS is in WGS 84, which is also the case for my QGIS (CRS = WGS84 (ID EPSG:4326). I do not really know what to set for position format in my GPS, so I let hddd.dddddd°: this could be the reason of my mistake? I also decided to create directly my points by clicking on my map on QGIS to see if the problem what coming from this, but again it is still not working as I got the exact same problem with my points landing north-eastwards. Any thoughts?

Comment: It seems to me like the maps in the GPS devices are shifted (south-weastwards maybe).